# Как открывать файлы в phpstorm в правильной кодировке?

Tags: php, phpstorm

Если через Notepad++ подключаюсь по ftp/sftp к серверу, то файлы открываются в кодировке, вкоторой они на сервере и я могу работать с ними, сохранять не боясь, что поломаю кодировку. В phpstorm же когда открываю, очень часто знаки вопроса, нужно постоянно переоткрывать в новой кодировке, заходить на сайт, смотреть в какой.
Как правильно открывать файлы сразу в кодировке, в которой они лежат на сервере?

Comment: Какие именно кодировки файлов на сервере и в какой именно кодировке открывает PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm  устанавливает свою кодировку в проекте. Какую кодировку? - Зависит от настроек проекта. Что бы их посмотреть/отредактировать зайдите crtl-alt-s ->File Encodings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте поменять кодировку на 'System default'.

Comment: Все равно... у меня в SysDef как и у вас пишет 1251, хотя все файлы например в UTF-8.
Но например, если на сайте есть док. разных код., они будут открываться только в той, котороу я тут задал?.. Тоже не выход из ситуации.

Comment: вы system default и там и там поставили?

Comment: поставил в двоих случаях